# NSTimer - sequence of activities - how to invalidate timer?

Tags: ios, nstimer

I would like to make a sequence of activities (A and B) using 2 timers.
I get some problems with timer invalidate...
Is this the correct way to proceed?
Thank you!!!

```
timerAStart = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(startActivityA) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
timerAStop = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(StopA) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
timerBStart = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(startActivityB) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
timerBStop = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4 target:self selector:@selector(StopB) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
- (void) StopA {
[timerAStart invalidate];
timerAStart=nil;
}
- (void) StopB {
[timerBStart invalidate];
timerBStart=nil;
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having with `invalidate`?

Comment: an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the line [timerAStart invalidate];

Comment: are you using arc or manual retain count?

Comment: i'm using arc; i declared NSTimer *TimerStart , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to invalidate since your timer is non-repeating.  If you look at the documentation you'll see that non-repeating timers self-invalidate.

Comment: ok, i agree... my problem so is that A is an infinite loop.... I could i stop it?

Comment: So are you saying that startActivityA results in an infinite loop? Can you post the code for that?

Comment: Dancreek, your answer has given me the right way to proceed... i've to change approach, and find something to exit from the loop like a counter... thanks a lot! ciao